# Why doesn't this ruby code do anything?

Tags: ruby

I am running the following ruby code in my local environment:

```
def multiples(max)
    array = []
    (0...max).each do |n|
        if (n % 3 == 0) || (n % 5 == 0)
            array << n
        end
    end
    array.inject(:+)

end

multiples(1000)
```

and nothing happens at all.  My code looks good to me.  What's the issue here?

Comment: What result are you expecting? Can you provide an example with a lower number?

Comment: _"nothing happens at all"_ What do you expect to happen?

Comment: I'm expecting it to return the sum of all the numbers in array

Comment: This does exactly that. Why do you think it doesn't do it?

Comment: It doesn't work when I run it as a script in the terminal for some reason..even when I use puts

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure what you're expecting, but if I paste your code into `irb` it does in fact do something.

```
> multiples(1000)
233168
```

If you are running your code as a command-line Ruby script, then perhaps you want to print this value so you can see the result on the console? In that case you want to use `puts`:

```
puts multiples(1000)
```

Comment: I'm running it as a command line ruby script, and I added the puts but I still get nothing?

Comment: Sorry, I don't know what else to say. I pasted your exact code (with the addition of `puts`) into a file named multiples.rb and then ran `ruby multiples.rb` and it printed out `233168`.

Comment: It works in irb..nothing when I run the script with ruby script.rb.  I'll accept in a minute